# Install problem Telegram on RPI3

Tags: raspbian-jessie, software-installation

I do the steps as written on [github.com/vysheng/tg.git](http://github.com/vysheng/tg.git) but after make I get an error.

```
inter -ggdb -Wno-unused-parameter -fPIC -iquote ./tgl -c -MP -MD -MF dep/crypto/bn_openssl.d -MQ objs/crypto/bn_openssl.o -o objs/crypto/bn_openssl.o tgl/crypto/bn_openssl.c
gcc -I. -I. -I./tgl -g -O2  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/lua5.2  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-deprecated-declarations -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-omit-frame-pointer -ggdb -Wno-unused-parameter -fPIC -iquote ./tgl -c -MP -MD -MF dep/crypto/bn_altern.d -MQ objs/crypto/bn_altern.o -o objs/crypto/bn_altern.o tgl/crypto/bn_altern.c
gcc -I. -I. -I./tgl -g -O2  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/lua5.2  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-deprecated-declarations -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-omit-frame-pointer -ggdb -Wno-unused-parameter -fPIC -iquote ./tgl -c -MP -MD -MF dep/crypto/rsa_pem_openssl.d -MQ objs/crypto/rsa_pem_openssl.o -o objs/crypto/rsa_pem_openssl.o tgl/crypto/rsa_pem_openssl.c
tgl/crypto/rsa_pem_openssl.c: In function ‘TGLC_rsa_new’:
tgl/crypto/rsa_pem_openssl.c:41:6: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘RSA {aka struct rsa_st}’
   ret->e = unwrap_bn (TGLC_bn_new ());
      ^~
tgl/crypto/rsa_pem_openssl.c: In function ‘TGLC_rsa_n’:
tgl/crypto/rsa_pem_openssl.c:52:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
 RSA_GETTER(n);
 ^~~~~~~~~~
tgl/crypto/rsa_pem_openssl.c: In function ‘TGLC_rsa_e’:
tgl/crypto/rsa_pem_openssl.c:53:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
 RSA_GETTER(e);
 ^~~~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors

Makefile.tgl:20: recept voor doel 'objs/crypto/rsa_pem_openssl.o' is mislukt
make: *** [objs/crypto/rsa_pem_openssl.o] Fout 1

pi@raspberrypi:~/tg $ bin/telegram-cli -k <public-server-key>
bash: syntaxfout nabij onverwacht symbool 'newline'
pi@raspberrypi:~/tg $ bin/telegram-cli -k tg-server.pub
bash: bin/telegram-cli: Bestand of map bestaat niet
pi@raspberrypi:~/tg $
```

Comment: Please: 1)reformat your dump as a code block 2) start programs prefixed by LANG=C so we see english messages. 3) all warnings being treated as errors is most likely why the compilation stops.

Comment: Add info as OS version and version of the lib's that was installed, ref github.com

Comment: Found this answer at https://github.com/vysheng/tgl/issues/129 refering to a pach for `tgl/crypto/rsa_pem_openssl.c:41:6: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘RSA {aka struct rsa_st}’`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev
```

Comment: It might be helpful to the OP and other readers to explain why this might be the solution; perhaps you could [edit] to explain why this works?